# Do we need the tags "mac" and "pc"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a reason should keep the [mac](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [pc](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) tags? The questions tagged with [mac](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [pc](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) are typically about [software](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) or connecting [instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments) or [midi](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midi) devices to a [computer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer).

Also there are two questions that share the [mac](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [pc](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) tags, but each tag only has 3 questions asked so there really only 2 questions that have them tagged uniquely.

Answer (score 3):

Do we NOT need the tags [mac](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [pc](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc)?

I imagine there's definitely the potential for [mac](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) specific questions. (Sods law - a fitting example of which has just popped up today.) And accordingly, there should a pc-specific option too.

In place of tagging both, I'd guess [computer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) would be a sensible substitute - however whilst tags aren't hierachical, there's nothing to prevent people using all three. I guess it's equivalent to tagging a generic guitar question with all of [electric-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-guitar)[acoustic-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-guitar)[guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar). ([link](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar+electric-guitar+acoustic-guitar))

Comment: Just because something can be tagged doesn't mean it should be. OS can be important information, but it can be information given in the question not the tags. I also know for a fact there have been unix software based questions and we don't have a unix tag. What I'm saying based on the focus of the questions there really doesn't seem to be a need for the tag. A mac or pc tag doesn't really tell us much about the music aspects of the post nor do I think anyone will search by the tags mac or pc or favorite or ignore them rendering them pretty useless tags if they stay.

Comment: I disagree - I think that some who has done significant amount of music production with a mac may follow such a tag.

Comment: In fact, someone already does. (Promise it's not me!)